# How to get HTML of an element when using Poltergeist?

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using Capybara with the Poltergeist driver. My question is: how to get the HTML (string) of a node?

I've read that using the RackTest driver you can get it like this:

```
find("table").native         #=> native Nokogiri element
find("table").native.to_html #=> "..."
```

But with Poltergeist calling `#native` on a node returns a `Capybara::Poltergeist::Node`, not a native Nokogiri element. And then calling `#native` again on the `Capybara::Poltergeist::Node` returns the same `Capybara::Poltergeist::Node` again (that is, it returns `self`).

It has become slightly irritating having to look at the HTML from the entire page to find what I'm looking for :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am adding this answer for others who land here. The solution is dead simple.

following the example you provided it would be:

```
find("table")['outerHTML']
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question! thank you

Answer (score 2):

I also find Poltergeist irritating. Here's what I did:

```
def nokogiri(selector)
    nokogiri = Nokogiri::HTML(page.html);
    return nokogiri.css(selector)[0]
end
```

This takes a css selector, and returns a native nokogiri element, rather than poltergeist's idiocy. You'll also have to `require 'nokogiri'`, but it shouldn't be a problem since it's a dependency for poltergeist.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't enough for me. When I'm working with Poltergeist's nodes, I usually tend to go deeper in the HTML hierarchy, and it would take me too much time to figure out how to write a CSS selector for a specific node. I don't find Poltergeist irritating, nor should you :)

Answer (score -1):

Its can be done like this

lets say on google.co.in you wana fetch INDIA

[image]

on step.rb file under your function write this line

```
x =  page.find(:xpath,'//*[@id="hplogo"]/div' , :visible => false).text
puts x
```

x will display "India"

Terminal o/p

[image]

Comment: I wasn't asking for the text, I was asking for the actual HTML.